# Extend a class without changing a base algorithm implementation?

Tags: c#, oop, interval-tree

I'm writing an interval tree in C#. What I'd like to do is just extend an existing binary search tree to store intervals and not have to rewrite the core functionality (add, get, delete).

Inside the BST, I have a `Node` class:

```
protected class Node 
{
    public KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> Data;
    public Node Left, Right;

    public Node(KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> data,
        Node left = null, Node right = null)
    {
        Data = data;
        Left = left; Right = right;
    }
}
```

And inside the interval tree, I have an `IntervalNode` class that extends `Node`:

```
private class IntervalNode : Node
{
    public Interval<TInterval> Interval;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("A={0}, B={1}", Interval.A, Interval.B);
    }

    public IntervalNode(KeyValuePair<TInterval, TVal> data, 
        Node left = null, Node right = null)
        : base(data, left, right)
    {
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is trying to store `IntervalNode` in the tree rather than `Node`. Is there any way I can now use the existing base implementations of `Add` with `IntervalNode`?

```
protected Node Add(Node root, KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> data)
{
    // regular binary search tree insert
}
```

I guess what I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
public void Add(Interval<TInterval> intvl, TVal val)
{
    _root = Add((Node)_root, new KeyValuePair<TInterval, TVal>(intvl.A, val));
    IntervalNode inserted = (IntervalNode)Get(_root, intvl.A);
    inserted.Interval = intvl;
}

// tree should store IntervalNodes, not Nodes
private IntervalNode _root;
```

Comment: By inheriting from Note class can't you already use Add method of Node?

Comment: you mean `base.Add`?

Comment: @Grundy: I want to store `IntervalNode` in the tree, though, not `Node`.

Comment: can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: Checkout the template design pattern : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: You don't need to cast for add, IntervalNode is a Node. You just need to cast on Get

Comment: @Burimi: Any way to do it without overriding? The insertion algorithm for `Node` and `IntervalNode` will be the same.

Comment: `public void Add` is a method from what class? node or tree?

Comment: @Grundy: `IntervalTree` which sub-classes the bst implementation.

Comment: @rookie if you need call method from base class you can use [_base_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code won't compile, but here is what I think you are trying to get at:

```
protected class Node
    {
        public KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> Data;
        public Node Left, Right;

        public Node(KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> data,
            Node left = null, Node right = null)
        {
            Data = data;
            Left = left; Right = right;
        }

        public virtual void Add(Node root, KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> data)
        {
            //Do whatever
        }
    }
```

Then in the derived class:

```
private class IntervalNode: Node
    {
        public Interval<TInterval> Interval;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("A={0}, B={1}", Interval.A, Interval.B);
        }

        public IntervalNode(KeyValuePair<TInterval, TVal> data, 
            Node left = null, Node right = null)
            : base(data, left, right)
        {
        }

        public override void Add(Node root, KeyValuePair<TInterval, TVal> data)
        {
            //Do whatever you need to, then
            base.Add(root, data);
        }
    }
```

You'll need to fix the generics problem you have but you should be able to see the point.

Since `IntervalNode` is a `Node`, you can store it in the same place that the base class does, there isn't a need to cast it or to separate the storage out. That is a nice part about inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. `Node` and `IntervalNode` are both inner classes of `BinarySearchTree` and `IntervalTree` respectively. I will look into your solution.